# Files Saving with a .5 File Extension

Tags: windows-10, adobe-illustrator

When I save an adobe file and I name it with .5 at the end, it saves this as a 5 File and not an adobe file (file name example: Print_Banner-240x25.5) My coworkers do not have this problem and wonder if there is a setting on my PC that I can change.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SuperUser . What exactly does the save window have as the filename before you enter your name (*Print_Banner-240x25.5*), does it perhaps show the correct file extension in file name field, and you overwrite it?

Comment: Maybe your coworkers are manually appending the correct extension in the save dialog.